# How can I rotate the screen of a MacBook Pro 90 degrees?

Tags: macos, macbook, display, orientation

How can I rotate the screen of a MacBook Pro 90 degrees to read content like books?

Comment: You're planning to rotate the screen and then tip the MBP on its side?

Comment: What software are you using to view these books? Perhaps one solution is to find software that lets you rotate the content (like PDF readers).

Comment: Bah, @Doug Chase beat me to it!

Comment: Yes, I plan to put the MBP on its side.

Comment: I'm using the built in PDF viewer.

Comment: So the built in PDF viewer does not support rotation?

Comment: Yes it does. So it wouldbe easier to just rotate the entire document and, if you like, putit into fullscreen and have a whole page fill the screen. That would be the best option in your case.

Comment: EasyPivot is not available any longer...

Comment: http://www.magesw.com/displayrotation/

Comment: Another reason not to use Apple devices.

Answer (score 56):

1. If System preferences is open, close it (this only work once after opening system preferences. I have no idea why)
2. press and hold <kbd>option/alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + left click 'Display'
3. Now there should be a button that says 'Rotation: Standard', click it and choose your rotation

Word of caution - it may be tricky to navigate the mousepad with a rotated screen. You feel drunk.

Comment: awesome trick - where do u ppl get this s.. :) ?

Comment: helped me a lot.Thanx

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer!

Comment: There's a driver patch for linux that rotates the touchpad, too. :D

Comment: Why is it like this? And where is this secret book of unknown shortcuts?

Comment: It's a good thing Apple hides these kinds of things ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Ｗorks like a charm! Thanks and wonder how you know this trick!

Comment: macOS 12, still working. (still only works once after opening system preferences, too)

Comment: Not working for me on MacOS 14.4 Sonoma.

Answer (score 9):

Hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>, click on **Preferences** and then on **Display** while **holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd>**. Only than you'll be given the option to change the rotation of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

I am running Windows XP on a MacBook and have found while holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd> keys together and pressing the cursor move keys (<kbd>home</kbd> <kbd>pgup</kbd> <kbd>pgdn</kbd> <kbd>end</kbd>) orients the screen in the direction of the cursor key.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X 10.6.8:

System Preferences -> Displays -> Rotation is a hidden setting:

1. Go to System Preferences (in the Apple menu).
2. While holding the alt/option and command keys, click 'Displays'.
3. Adjust the Rotation setting. (If you don't see it, close System Preferences and start over.)
4. A popup entitled "Confirm new display setting" appears.
5. Rotate the physical screen.
6. In the popup, click "Confirm" or "Revert".

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 10.7.5

Comment: edited to emphasize that this answer is for Mac OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

According to
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9290419
the hardware supports the act of displaying sideways, but it appears that only [SMSRotateD](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164014/https://osxbook.com/software/sms/smsrotated/) makes use of this.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the screen when reading a PDF or word file, simply hold <kbd>control</kbd> and right click the mouse. You can rotate the screen, and your mouse, etc. still runs the same, so you won't get disoriented.

Answer (score -2):

On MBP's with multi-touch, you can rotate content in Preview.app using the 'two finger swirl' ;) or you can use cmd-L or cmd-R. This works in OX 10.5.x, but I don't know about earlier versions.

Comment: It really only rotates the current page, am I wrong? And then it can even be saved, destroying the PDF.

Comment: cmd-L gives you the option to rotate the entire document and there's no reason you can rotate it back later, or not save the doc after you rotate it.